# Off canvas using checkbox Not working on Android 4.1.2

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying this side menu off canvas

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nav-checkbox">
<label for="nav-checkbox" class="icon-menu"></label>
<label for="nav-checkbox" class="body-trigger"></label>
<aside class="off-canvas">
</aside>
```

scss:

```
#nav-checkbox {
  display: none;

  &:checked {
    & ~ .off-canvas {
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    & ~ .body-trigger {
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  }
}

.icon-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 1.625em;
  height: .313em;
  background: black;
  margin: 1.5em;
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
  z-index: 1;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
    width: 1.625em;
    height: .313em;
  }

  &::before {
    top: -.625em;
  }

  &::after {
    bottom: -.625em;
  }
}

.body-trigger {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 17.5em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.off-canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: -17.5em;
  width: 17.5em;
  height: 100%;
  background: #f5f5f5;  
  transition: left 0.3s ease;
  z-index:2;
}
```

It working well in browser and android lolipop . But not working in my android jelly bean . The checkbox is tick when you click the icon but it dont bring out the canvas.

Here code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJMyJp

Thank you

Comment: It's seems to be bug. Because if you set the checkbox to `checked` in the first place, the `:checked` css rule is working. The browser doesn't "update" the state after the click.

Comment: @MoshFeu I see . So the only way to achieve this with js ? (not really love js)

Comment: Code tip @SahalSaad you should not animate on the `left` property rather use `transform: translate-x();`. Animating on position alters the geometry of the element. That means that it may affect the position or size of other elements on the page, both of which require the browser to perform layout operations.

Once those layout operations have completed any damaged pixels will need to be painted and the page must then be composited together.